# wxSmith and Code::Blocks build error

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I recently started to work on GUI using wxSmith on Code::Blocks 10.05, and when I run the project, I haven't written any code yet, just the OnClose function, and I when I build and run my project, I get 4 errors, `cannot find -lwxmsw28d_core`, `cannot find -lwxbase28d`, `cannot find -lwxpngd`, and `cannot find -lwxzlibd`.
The build log is:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in gui-test ---------------

Compiling: gui_testMain.cpp
Linking executable: bin\Debug\gui-test.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw28d_core.a when searching for -lwxmsw28d_core
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_core.a when searching for -lwxmsw28d_core
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw28d_core.a when searching for -lwxmsw28d_core
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw28d_core
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxbase28d.a when searching for -lwxbase28d
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d.a when searching for -lwxbase28d
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxbase28d.a when searching for -lwxbase28d
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxbase28d
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxpngd.a when searching for -lwxpngd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib\libwxpngd.a when searching for -lwxpngd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxpngd.a when searching for -lwxpngd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxpngd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxzlibd.a when searching for -lwxzlibd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib\libwxzlibd.a when searching for -lwxzlibd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_lib/libwxzlibd.a when searching for -lwxzlibd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxzlibd
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
4 errors, 0 warnings
```

What could be giving me the error?
I'm using Code::Blocks on Windows. And I'm doing as a tutorial what this link is doing [wxSmith Tutorial - Code::Blocks Wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxSmith_tutorial%3a_Hello_world)

NOTE: If it helps, I installed wxWidgets from wxPack, and in Code::Blocks, I made a Global Variable using the Global Variable Editor, where the base field has `C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8`, include field has `C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\include`, and lib field has `C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib`. The rest of the fields are empty, like the obj (i couldnt find obj folder), cflags, lflags, and user-defined fields are empty.

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit computer but installed the 32-bit version, or the other way around?

Comment: I'm on 64-bit Windows, and in wxPack there wasn't 32-bit or 64-bit versions, only 1 file http://wxpack.sourceforge.net/Main/Downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if you did not compile the correct Debug version of wxWidgets.

Look at your ...\wxWidgets\build\msw folder, is there a folder like

- gc_mwsud (unicode debug)
- gc_mswuddll (unicode debug shared)

and in your case a folder

- gcc_mswd (debug)
- gcc_mswddll (debug shared)

**EDIT**

**Only for your special case**

go to x:\wxWidgets\build\msw\ **( x == your drive)**

change your x:\wxWidgets\build\msw\config.gcc like

```
....

# C compiler 
CC = gcc

# C++ compiler 
CXX = g++
....

# What type of library to build? [0,1]
SHARED = 0
....

# Compile Unicode build of wxWidgets? [0,1]
UNICODE = 0
....

# Type of compiled binaries [debug,release]
BUILD ?= debug
....

# Multiple libraries or single huge monolithic one? [0,1]
MONOLITHIC = 0
```

**make with command. ONLY for your special case !!**

x:\wxWidgets\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc

**The normal way for the officially-supported Code::Blocks is**

clean up the source:

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug clean

NOTE: Make sure you use exactly the same options for this step and for the build step below. The clean target uses these variables and only cleans the specified version of the generated object and library files. (It will not clean the intended files if these variables are not identical.)

NOTE: If you still have problems with compiling after cleaning, you could try to manually remove the gcc_mswd directory under the build\msw directory. This directory is the place where the object files are stored.

When everything is clean you can start compiling wxWidgets:

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc  MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug

NOTE: These options are the officially-supported Code::Blocks options. If you want another version of wxWidgets (debug or non-Unicode) you still have to make sure you build a MONOLITHIC version (one big DLL) for linking Code::Blocks.

Patience. This step takes time. Make sure there was no compilation error before you continue.

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Compiling_wxWidgets_2.8.6_to_develop_Code::Blocks_%28MSW%29

Comment: No, the only folders I have are: "vc_mswddll", "vc_mswdll", "vc_mswuddll", and "vc_mswudll"

Comment: You must compile for gcc_lib with debug. Look at my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

"Incompatible" almost certainly means that the library is a 32 bit file and you're using 64 bit compiler. Run `file` on both the library and one of the object files generated during your build from MinGW command line to confirm this.

If this is correct, the solution would be to add `-m32` option to the compiler/linker command lines if they really generate 64 bit code by default. Or maybe just get a 32 bit version of the compiler.

Comment: How can I run `file`, and is MinGW command line different from the command prompt?

Comment: I think you should have a shortcut to bash installed by MinGW/MSYS installation. And file should be available, i.e. just "file name-of-the-file".

Comment: Okay, I was able to open the MinGW command line, but what do you mean by `both library and one of the object files generated during you build`? I'm kinda new to the whole bash commands and MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

while making a new project just check the option that wxwidget is built as a monolithic library with use wxwidget DLL option.!
if already created project just add linker settings and compiler settings of the project (properties)